# Haskell: How to memoize this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, performance, haskell, dynamic-programming, memoization

I wrote this solution to the [coin change problem on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/coin-change/problem):

```
makeChange :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
makeChange n ys = go n (sort ys)
    where go _ [] = 0
          go n (x:xs)
            | x == n = 1
            | x > n = 0
            | otherwise = (makeChange n xs) + (makeChange (n - x) (x:xs))
```

However it times out on some of the larger test cases. I saw [this](http://travis.athougies.net/posts/2018-05-05-dynamic-programming-is-recursion.html) article on implementing memoization using `let` bindings but it mostly went over my head and I'm not sure how I would implement that here. Any help?

I rewrote it and got a substantial performance improvement, but i'm still timing out on the hacker rank exercise:

```
makeChange' :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
makeChange' =
    let go _ [] = 0
        go n (x:xs)
          | x == n = 1
          | x > n = 0
          | otherwise = (makeChange' n xs) + (makeChange' (n - x) (x:xs))
    in go

f (x:y:xs) = makeChange' x ys
    where ys = sort xs
main = interact $ show . f . map read . words
```

I moved the pre-sort into an intermediate function `f` which I am also using to handle the input from Hacker Rank. They give you a string with the change target, the length of the change array, and the array of change units. I use `f` to drop the length from the input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem does *not* need memoization. If `a` is an *infinite length* list where `a !! n` is the total number of ways to make a total sum of `n` with some set of coins, and you get a new distinct coin of value `x`, you can update the list `a` to the new list `b` using the facts that:

- The first `x` elements will not change; because, you cannot use the new coin for a sum less than `x`. so, `take x a`.
- For the remaining elements:

  ```
  b(n) = a(n) + b(n - x)
  ```

  where the first summand means do not use the new coin at all, and the 2nd summand means use it at least once.

This can be simply implemented using a right fold, with initial value `[1, 0, 0, ...]`, because with no coins the only sum you may make is zero. Haskell laziness is also very useful here:

```
solve :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
solve n xs = (foldr go (1:repeat 0) xs) !! n
  where go x a = let b = (take x a) ++ zipWith (+) b (drop x a) in b
```

then:

```
\> solve 4 [1, 2, 3]
4
\> solve 10 [2, 5, 3, 6]
5
```

as in the examples in the question.

Comment: Briliiant. And seems significantly faster than the array version in Probie's answer.

Comment: Wow looks like an amazing solution. Its way beyond my skill level to understand it at this point, but i'm trying to work through it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is best solved with an explicit 2D array. In effect, we give the result of each function call a location in this array. This allows us to only need to evaluate function at most once. There's a tiny bit more boilerplate we have to add, because we need to check if we'd index outside the array

```
makeChange :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
makeChange n ys = arr ! (n,1)
    where 
      len = length xs
      xs = sort ys
      arr = array ((1,1),(n,len)) [((i,j), go i j x)| i <- [1..n], (j,x) <- zip [1..] xs]
      go n ix x | x == n = 1
                | x > n = 0
                | otherwise = (if ix + 1 <= len then (arr ! (n, ix+1)) else 0) + 
                              (if (n-x) > 0 then (arr ! ((n-x), ix)) else 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to demonstrate how behzad.nouri's code is working in an effort to understand it myself:

Keeping in mind Haskell's laziness, we observe that `!! n` means our final list will be evaluated up to it's `(n+1)`th element. Our main block for each coin is:

```
let b = (take x a) ++ zipWith (+) b (drop x a) in b
```

There's a little trick here that works because `b` is a list. Note that a similar kind of self-reference wouldn't work if `b` were an integer. Let's say our only coin was 2:

```
 > let b = (take 2 [1,0,0,0,0]) ++ zipWith (+) b (drop 2 [1,0,0,0,0]) in b
=> [1,0,1,0,1]
```

(Which means one way to make zero, one way to make two, and one way to make four.) What happens is `b` gets built recursively as it's self-referenced until there is a length match for the zip evaluation:

```
 > zipWith (+) [] (drop 2 [1,0,0,0,0])
=> []
-- But we prepended [1,0] so the next `b` is [1,0]
 > zipWith (+) [1,0] (drop 2 [1,0,0,0,0])
=> [1,0]
-- But we prepended [1,0] so the next `b` is [1,0,1,0]
 > zipWith (+) [1,0,1,0] (drop 2 [1,0,0,0,0])
=> [1,0,1]
-- But we prepended [1,0] so the result matching the length is [1,0,1,0,1]
```

Now let's use this knowledge to follow through `solve 4 [1,2,3]`:

```
let b = (take 3 [1,0,0,0,0]) ++ zipWith (+) b (drop 3 [1,0,0,0,0]) in b

take 3 [1,0,0,0,0] -- n+1 elements are evaluated from the infinite list
=> [1,0,0]

++       [0,0] -- drop 3 from [1,0,0,0,0]
     (+) []
     =>  []
     -- prepend [1,0,0]
     =>  [1,0,0]

++       [0,0]
     (+) [1,0,0]
     =>  [1,0]
     -- prepend [1,0,0]
     =>  [1,0,0,1,0]
```

That's one way to make zero and one way to make three. Next:

```
let b = (take 2 [1,0,0,1,0]) ++ zipWith (+) b (drop 2 [1,0,0,1,0]) in b

take 2 [1,0,0,1,0]
=> [1,0]

++     [0,1,0]
   (+) []
   =>  []
   -- prepend [1,0]
   =>  [1,0]

++     [0,1,0]
   (+) [1,0]
   =>  [1,1,0]
   -- prepend [1,0]
   =>  [1,0,1,1,0]

++     [0,1,0]
   (+) [1,0,1,1,0]
   =>  [1,1,1]
   -- prepend [1,0]
   =>  [1,0,1,1,1]
```

That's one way to make 0, one way to make 2, one way to make 3, and one way to make 4. Next:

```
let b = (take 1 [1,0,1,1,1]) ++ zipWith (+) b (drop 1 [1,0,1,1,1]) in b
```

This is the one with the most iterations since `b` is built from just one element

```
take 1 [1,0,1,1,1]
=> [1]

++   [0,1,1,1]
 (+) []
 =>  []
 -- prepend [1]
 =>  [1]

++   [0,1,1,1]
 (+) [1]
 =>  [1]
 -- prepend [1]
 =>  [1,1]

++   [0,1,1,1]
 (+) [1,1]
 =>  [1,2]
 -- prepend [1]
 =>  [1,1,2]

++   [0,1,1,1]
 (+) [1,1,2]
 =>  [1,2,3]
 -- prepend [1]
 =>  [1,1,2,3]

++   [0,1,1,1]
 (+) [1,1,2,3]
 =>  [1,2,3,4]
 -- prepend [1]
 =>  [1,1,2,3,4]
```

That's 1 way to make 0, 1 way to make 1, 2 ways to make 2, 3 ways to make 3, and 4 ways to make 4.